# How to mock SOAP web service without SoapUI

Tags: web-services, soap, mocking

I have a web service that I want to mock in following way: I will have a list of given IDs, and a set of response items for them, and if user will send a request with ID from the list, proper response should be sent back.
How to do it without tools like SoapUI (I don't want to install any additional software on the server that will be tested if possible).
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5):

SoapUI open source provides exactly what you want to achieve, without any need to install SoapUI on the server.

I consider this approach very efficient:

1. Create your mock service inside SoapUI.
2. Test the mock on your computer with SoapUI.
3. Create a WAR with the mock service (or more services) - just click on the project and choose "Deploy As WAR"
4. Deploy the WAR to the target server.

The resulting WAR is standalone and you do not need to deploy any other software.

I recommend this tutorial: https://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/getting-started.html

Regards,
Karel

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I could find is https://www.mockable.io/  . Hope it helps.

Comment: im trying to get response from mocable io but I can get response

Answer (score 0):

You might have to build an actual mock for this.

This could range from just a different implementation for an existing interface (say IOrderQuerier, with the old OrderQuerier and the new MockOrderQuerier), to a different project altogether (say MockOrderApi).

In both scenarios, the Mock would just return a set of predefined values depending on the input, but you'll need to provide some sort of switch mechanism (for example a flag in the config file, which is read by the DI container).

You'll have to provide more details about the server if you need more targeted answers on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage to mock this using mockito, I've just added a simple project which does most of the heavy lifting: [mockito-soap-cxf](https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf)